# ember save call not going to success block

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember save call on model to persist and invoke my REST call.

```
_model.save().then(() =>{
   console.log("success");
 }, (error) {
    console.log("error");
 });
```

My REST api returned 202 response (as seen on network tab) and on console I always see "Error" getting printed. Is there anything in ember which treats 202 as an error? if yes, how can it be fixed?

Comment: shouldn't it be `then((error) =>{...` Never used ember btw :)

Comment: no it is correct, but dont know why its going to error block.

Comment: what version of ember is this?

can you use async/await?

Answer (score 2):

Ember Data tries to parse the response body as JSON for certain status codes including 202. An empty string is not a valid JSON. Therefore it throws an error as you have mentioned in some comment:

> SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data"

Since it throws, the Promise returned by `save()` is rejected.

You have two options:

- Return a valid JSON from your backend.
- Change the default behavior of Ember Data to not parse a 202 response as JSON.

Please note that `{}` would be a valid JSON but not be compliant with JSON API specification:

> A JSON object MUST be at the root of every JSON API request and
>   response containing data. This object defines a document’s “top
>   level”.
>
> A document MUST contain at least one of the following top-level
>   members:
>
> - data: the document’s “primary data”
> - errors: an array of error objects
> - meta: a meta object that contains non-standard meta-information.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use native promise hooks for this, like:

```
model.save()
  .then((idk) => {
     console.log('idk', idk);
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
  });
```

or if you have the ability to use async/await:

```
   try {
     await model.save();
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
```

both of these snippets will tell you why you have an error, if you have an error :)

Comment: have u tried this with a response (202 status code)?

Comment: what's the content of the error variable in your snippet?

Comment: So, there is no error in the backend as I can see the whole process gets completed. Somehow ember treating 202 as an error. (thats what I can understand).

Comment: Give me some time, I will reset and invoke again on my end.

Comment: printed error and it seems like may be backend has some issues: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: but cant a backend API returns a blank response and ember shall be handling it based on status codes? or do I need to override adapters to handle such cases?

Comment: if you inspect the network tab of your browsers dev tools, what does it show?

do you have API tests to ensure that your endpoint is returning a resource?

I believe jsonapi (not just ember-data) expects that a full resource is returned on  on POST/PATCH/PUT

Comment: unless maybe 204 (No Content) is used? (unsure about this one)

Comment: so it worked but if i print the response on console, it gives me the same data i sent as a post params over the wire and not the actual response i saw on network tab? anyone know anything about it?

Comment: do you have control over your API? I guess, I need to know more information about the overall request lifecycle.

Comment: No, i dont have control over API. All i can do is track on dev tools.

Comment: how much customizing of the serializer and adapter have you done?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your `template.hbs` has something like these

```
  {{#each model as |myModel|}}
    <tr>
      <td {{action 'saveMe' myModel}}> {{myModel.someAttribute}} </td>
  </tr>
 {{/each}}
```

Then, your `controller.js` should be look something like these

```
actions: {
  saveMe(myModel) {
    return myArgument.save().then(() => {
      console.log('foo success');
    }).catch(errors => {
      console.log('bar error');
    });
  }
}
```

The action does is to save the changes of the value of an attribute you would like to change.

Answer (score 0):

seems like issue is fixed. My response was blank and hence ember was throwing it into error response. Even with 202 response, something shall be returned from the back end or one has to override handleResponse method in application adapter.